VTPK to PBF issue, where some tiles are incomplete
I am having this issue where I have a street premium license, and I am currently developing a web application.  My issue is that when I use the ArcGIS tool to convert the vtpk that is in the mmpk package, to pbf format in the exploded view.  I am not able to use the data, because I am using Leaflet js to display the map, but it is incomplete when I am zoomed in at the 14-16 zoom level.
I have been trying to figure out a way to solve this issue, but it almost seems like there is data missing from the tool that Arcgis has to convert to the exploded format.
I am using Django as a http server and serving this as static files for my pbf.  I have also used vtpk2mbtiles and it also shows that this is incomplete.  I don’t know if this issue is because I am using a single U.S. state’s vtpk, and maybe I should try North America mmpk or US mmpk.
I am open for ideas on why this may be happening and if anyone else has had this issue.
